# Costing calculation

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking, situation

A man went to a peculiar shop and enquires about prices. The dialogue between him and the shop owner goes like this:

**Man:** How much would 50 cost?

**Shop-owner:** 30 cents.

**Man:** How much would 5 cost?

**Shop-owner:** 15 cents.

Then how much would 100 cost and what kind of items are sold/bought?

Assume a *normal* and *fair* trade happened during transactions.

(Courtesy: Online /internet)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shop-keeper is selling:

> Door numbers. Each digit costs 15 cents, so 100 costs 45 cents.

Comment: it is correct ! Items can be individual numbers of sign boards / license plates etc.